# Single GoogleCredential and GmailService for multiple mailboxes

Tags: c#, .net, gmail-api, google-workspace

I'm creating a simple app that changes vacation settings for multiple g-suite users.
Currently, I'm creating GoogleCredential and GmailService objects per mailbox, like so:

```
var credentials = GoogleCredential.FromFile(FileName).CreateScoped(Scopes).CreateWithUser(User);

var gmailService = new GmailService(
    new BaseClientService.Initializer()
    {
        ApplicationName = ApplicationName,
        HttpClientInitializer = credentials
    });

var x = gmailService.Users.GetProfile(User);
var y = await x.ExecuteAsync();

Console.WriteLine(y.MessagesTotal);

long now = (long)DateTime.UtcNow.Subtract(
    new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc)
).TotalMilliseconds;



VacationSettings settings = new VacationSettings
{
    EnableAutoReply = true,
    RestrictToDomain = false,
    ResponseBodyPlainText = "I'm on vacations :)",
    ResponseSubject = "Vacations",
    StartTime = now

};

UsersResource.SettingsResource.UpdateVacationRequest request = gmailService.Users.Settings.UpdateVacation(settings, "me");

var response = await request.ExecuteAsync();
```

The above code works fine, but I'm trying to reuse it for multiple mailboxes.
I've tried removing `CreateWithUser(User)` when creating GoogleCredential and calling API with specific email instead of "me", like so:

```
var req1 = gmailService.Users.Settings.UpdateVacation(settings, "a@example.com").Execute();
var req2 = gmailService.Users.Settings.UpdateVacation(settings, "b@example.com").Execute();
```

but I get below error:

```
Google.GoogleApiException
HResult=0x80131500
Message=Google.Apis.Requests.RequestError
Precondition check failed. [400]
Errors [
Message[Precondition check failed.] Location[ - ] Reason[failedPrecondition] Domain[global]
]
```

so I need some special scopes for my service account?
I asked this question in [google API repo on GitHub](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-dotnet-client/issues/1629), but I was suggested to ask it here to get an answer from Gmail API Team.

Is this even possible?

Comment: What line throws this error?

Comment: @RafaGuillermo `await request.ExecuteAsync();` Question is: do I need some special permission to modify other user's mailboxes? OR do I must impersonate every request?

Comment: You must impersonate every request individually. The delegated credentials are build with the subject included. Check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61932919/11551468) - it's node.je instead of C# but you can see how the creds are built.

Comment: @RafaGuillermo I'm doing that right now, but I was hoping I can impersonate as admin and settings for many mailboxes at once. I've posted the same question on GitHub and have answer from the team: https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-dotnet-client/issues/1629#issuecomment-678326541

Comment: You can't, it has to be one user at a time, an even as an admin you don't have mailbox rights for other domain users - you have to impoersonate the owner.