# how to set Google drive auth object for "google-drive-uploader" npm package

Tags: node.js, npm, google-drive-api

can someone guide me in creating a auth object for following code!

```
const upload = require('google-drive-uploader');
 
const {id, size, md5, mimeType} = await upload({
  path: '/path/to/file.mov',
  folderId: '...Google Drive folder ID...',
  auth: /* Google Drive auth object */
});
```

Answer (score 0):

### You have two options to obtain `auth`

1. The google-drive-uploader package provides its own authentication method: simply define

```js
const auth = await upload.authenticate({
  email: 'EMAIL',
  privateKey: 'PRIVATE KEY'
});
```

2. The conventional Google libray method is

```js
const {JWT} = require('google-auth-library');
 
const auth = new JWT(
  'EMAIL',
  null,
  'PRIVATE KEY',
  ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']
);
 
await auth.authorize();
```

## For both options, a privateKey is a credential that you obtain when creating a service account

In other words, to use this ppackage, you need to create a Google Service account, as described [here](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account#creatinganaccount)

- When working with a service account,  `EMAIL` is the email of the service account - not your own email
- When using a service account - you should give to the service account access to your drive - if you want it to upload files to your drive
- Alternatively you can use [impersonation](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account#authorizingrequests) in combination with domain-wide delegation
- The latter allows the service account to act as "you", so you do not need to exlicitly share with it your Drive and files
- See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61915432/google-oauth-using-domain-wide-delegation-and-service-account/61932919#61932919) for a sample on how to create a JWT authentication client with impersonation