# How to Authenticate Google Sheets API without User Interaction

Tags: node.js, google-sheets, google-api

I'm trying to access a private Google Sheet in a daily cronjob in order to populate a database. This job runs on a remote server. Currently I'm using the method outlined [here](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/nodejs#step_2_set_up_the_sample) to access the spreadsheet. The caveat is that every time the access token expires, a user has to manually go in and authenticate the request for a new access token by logging into their Google account. Is there a way to obtain an access token *without* user interaction?

Comment: Who is the script meant for? Users on your domain only, or also users on other domains/Google accounts?

Comment: @RafaGuillermo it's meant for users on my domain only. Ideally I would just have one account (like a service account) whose credentials are used for the script.

Comment: As far as I know, some Google APIs can be accessed using service account credentials [without OAuth](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account?authuser=1#jwt-auth). But I'm not sure how to get this to work with the Sheets API (if it even does work)

Comment: you then need to construct a JWT; check out my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61915432/google-oauth-using-domain-wide-delegation-and-service-account/61932919#61932919) which uses Drive, though AFAIK it also works with Sheets